# Nature of Excel 2010 VBA Embedded Chart Container

Tags: vba, excel, charts, shapes

I searched Google and on many different forums but cannot find the Physical Nature (I don't know to say it) of an Embedded Chart's container window, I mean the canvas like rectangular area which serves as, well, the chart container.

I know that it is a ChartObject.

**The main clarifications that I needed is:**

- Is it a Shape as in Autoshape or Freeform shape? (I suspect so)
  It does show up as a shape in Selection Pane.
  Copy/Pasting Freeform shapes onto it causes pasted shapes to stick onto it while doing the same with any other two shapes won't stick to each other.
- Is it a Userform? (I am skeptical)
  But Userforms are always in front of the shapes and shapes cannot be pasted onto userforms obviously.

Answer (score 0):

The `ChartObject` is also a `Shape` that can be reached via the Shapes collection.

```
?Sheet1.Shapes("Chart 1").Type = msoShapeType.msoChart
True
```